# Simple fusioncharts in MonoTouch not working

Tags: ios, uiwebview, mono, xamarin.ios, fusioncharts

I'm trying to embed a column3d chart from fusioncharts in my MonoTouch project using `UIWebView`. I've added the necessary outlets and tested by using loadrequest to load a url and `loadHtmlString` to format a simple line of text. This works fine. I even tested that fusionchart works correctly on my browser using the below code and it does.

I have a folder named "charts" in my MonoTouch project that contains, Column3d.swf, jquery.min.js, FusionCharts.js, FusionCharts.HC.js and FusionCharts.HC.Charts.js.

In my

- ViewDidLoad

  ```
  string htmlString = "<html>
                       <head>
                       <script type=\"text/javascript\"src=\"Charts/jquery.min.js\">
                       </script>
                       <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"Charts/FusionCharts.js\">
                       </script>
                       <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"Charts/FusionCharts.HC.js\">
                       </script>
                       <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"Charts/FusionCharts.HC.Charts.js\">
                       </script>
                       </head>
                       <body>
                       <div id=\"chartContainer\">FusionCharts will load here!
                       </div>
                       <script type=\"text/javascript\"> var myChart = new FusionCharts( \"Charts/Column3D.swf\", \"myChartId\", \"400\", \"300\", \"0\", \"1\" );myChart.setXMLUrl(\"Charts/Data.xml\");
                      myChart.render(\"chartContainer\");
                       </script>
                       </body>
                       </html>";

  this.webView.LoadHtmlString (htmlString, new NSUrl ("./Charts", true));

      /*string htmlString = "<html><head></head><body><span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">This</span> " +
   "<span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">is</span> <span style=\"font-style: italic;\">some formatted</span> " +"<span style=\"font-weight: bold;text-decoration: underline;\">text!</span><br></body></html>";*/  //works

      //this.webView.LoadHtmlString (htmlString, null);  //works
  ```
- Data.xml

  ```
  <chart caption='Weekly Sales Summary'
  xAxisName='Week' yAxisName='Amount' numberPrefix='$'> 
  <set label='Week 1' value='14400' /> 
  <set label='Week 2' value='19600' /> 
  <set label='Week 3' value='24000' /> 
  <set label='Week 4' value='15700' /> 
  </chart>
  ```

Can someone explain how I can get this working? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I also tried

```
    string htmlString = "<html><head> <title>Creating Pure JavaScript chart</title><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"charts/FusionCharts.js\"></script></head> <body><div id=\"chartContainer\">FusionCharts will load here!</div> <script type=\"text/javascript\">FusionCharts.setCurrentRenderer('javascript');var myChart = new FusionCharts( \"charts/Column3D.swf\", \"myChartId\", \"400\", \"300\", \"0\", \"1\" );myChart.setXMLData(\"<chart><set label='Data1' value='1' /></chart>\"); myChart.render(\"chartContainer\"); </script></body> </html>";
```

where i force the renderer to use javascript and set the chart parameters in the string to no avail. Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue and thought I would post it should someone run into a similar issue.

The first thing I did was to right click on each of my javscript files ie FusionCharts.js, FusionCharts.HC.js and FusionCharts.HC.Charts.js and set their build type to content.

I then told Monotouch the build path for the charts would be contained in the charts folder by declaring

```
string path = NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath + "/Charts/";
```

Since I declare i am going to look in the Charts folder for related files, I then had to amend my htmlString by removing the "charts" keyword reference from all the **"src"** as below (since we are already lo.

```
string htmlString = "<html>
                 <head>
                 <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"jquery.min.js\">
                 </script>
                 <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/FusionCharts.js\">
                 </script>
                 <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/FusionCharts.HC.js\">
                 </script>
                 <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"FusionCharts.HC.Charts.js\">
                 </script>
                 </head>
                 <body>
                 <div id=\"chartContainer\">FusionCharts will load here!
                 </div>
                 <script type=\"text/javascript\"> var myChart = new FusionCharts(\"Column3D.swf\", \"myChartId\", \"400\", \"300\", \"0\", \"1\"          );myChart.setXMLUrl(\"Charts/Data.xml\");
                myChart.render(\"chartContainer\");
                 </script>
                 </body>
                 </html>";
```

I then call the loadHtml string method as below with the second argument pointing to the path that contains the javascript files.

```
this.webView.LoadHtmlString(htmlString, new NSUrl(path, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I even tested that fusionchart works correctly on my browser using the below code and it does.

Did you test this with an iOS device running Safari ?

> project that contains, Column3d.swf,

That looks like a **Flash** file and iOS (and WebKit) does **not** support flash.

The [website](http://www.fusioncharts.com/products/suite/) hints of an HTML5 version - so if they support flash-less browser then you should be able to do what you want using MonoTouch (or anything in iOS) using FusionChart. Otherwise you might need to look at other charting products (or a server-side solution).

Comment: as i mention in the edit above. I force the renderer to only run with html5 to no avail. Also I am trying to get it to work in IOS, it works on my computer even when i use the pure javascript approach

Comment: Sadly I can't help you with anything fusionchart specific (never used it). However my original advice still stands. Ensure it works on iOS **devices** (not a computer) using Safari **first** , as it might need some extra/different configuration, then once it works try using the same in a `UIWebView` with MonoTouch.

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts had put out a blog post showing how to get HTML5 charts in iOS devices.

Have a look at it here - http://blog.fusioncharts.com/2012/02/create-charts-for-iphone-and-ipad-apps-using-fusioncharts-xt/

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. the link you provided is for xcode, I'm looking for a solution for monotouch. I think the issue is the monotouch libraries I have in the charts folder aren't included when reading the htmlString. Any suggestions on how I can get this working?

Comment: @JohnD We've created a sample app that uses MonoTouch and FusionCharts XT. Download it from here - http://blog.fusioncharts.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/FusionChartsXT_With_MonoTouch.zip. A blog post on the FusionCharts blog is coming soon.